# Import Oracle User Schema

Tags: sql, oracle, import, schema

I've got an oracle database with several users (Other Users?), and I would like to import an schema which is in an .sql file.

My doubt is how to specify on my .sql file that the import is for an specific user.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you going to use to do the 'import?' If you have a .sql file, you simply need to login to the database and execute that file or files...depending on what exactly is in it. For example, does the file have a CREATE USER in it, or is it just the schema objects itself?

Comment: This question is related to database administration (dba).  I suggest you ask this in http://dba.stackexchange.com/ 
They are going to provide you good solution since it's their specialty.

Answer (score 0):

Examine your sql file. If the commands in there specify a schema name, then you'll need to modify it before you can import it into a different schema.

For example, does it have commands like this:

```
CREATE TABLE scott.mytable (...)
```

or like:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (...)
```

If the schema name (e.g. "scott") has been hard-coded, then you'll need to edit your sql script to carefully remove it.

If not, then you just need to log in as the target username and run your sql script.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the content of your SQL file. You're not doing an import, you are running an SQL file, and that is a bit like "running a script" : it can contain anything. So, it's hard for us to tell from here, how you should run a file, to which we have no clue what is the content. There are many ways of defining the owner of an object. It can be done explicit, or implicit. So, that's a first thing to check : is a user (schema) specified IN the script ? If it is, where is it specified, and how ?

In the most simple case, people would just write a script that connects, and installs objects - in the current schema. Sometimes even without the connect. So, in that case you can call the script as any user you want the objects to be created in.

In the totally other way, you can have a script where a given owner, is specified at each object reference. In that case, you'll probably end up doing a global search and replace.

So, let us know how your script works, and we can detail.